# What is the right way to load heavy Task on android ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

As viewpager preload +1 and -1 of the fragment that is used in it. I've a loading of data using asyntask that i wish to execute only when i am on the page itself.

Where should i execute the function? oncreate does not seems to work for me

Comment: the whole point for the viewpager loading the previous and next pages is so that all the content is ready and loaded to when you get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided by Tanis should work, there's however one think that should be taken in consideration. Since the `AsyncTask` is started from `Activity`, you may encounter some issues when dealing with configuration changes. Perhaps starting the `AsyncTask` dirrectly from the fragment will make more sense.

The solution then would be to make the currently displayed fragment aware that he is the fragment displayed now.

Firstly, you should have a method in your Activity that will return the position of current fragment from `ViewPager`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

   //....
   public int getViewPagerCurrentIndex() {
    return pager.getCurrentItem();
   }
}
```

Secondly, in your `PagerAdapter` in `getItem()` method pass the position of current item as an argument to the fragment:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    //....

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

Lastly, check in `MyFragment` that both position returned from `MainActivity` and position received when the fragment was instantiated match. If they match then this instance of fragment is visible:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int position) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setRetainInstance(true);
   if (getArguments() != null) {            
    fragmentPosition = getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION);
   }
}

// It does not matter where this method is called, the AsyncTask will be started only for the currently visible fragment.
private void executeAsyncTask(){
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
    if (mainActivity.getViewPagerCurrentIndex() == fragmentPosition ) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and run your AsyncTask in `onPageSelected()`.

For example:

```
public class MyActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }
}
```

However, as Tyczj pointed out in the comments, this defeats the purpose of a ViewPager trying to keep Views loaded. This feature is designed to make your app look smooth, and without it your Views will look empty (or take on their default appearance) while you load your data.

Comment: `setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` won't work, as `ViewPager` enforces the lower limit of `DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES`, which is `1`.

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot about that. Thanks for the clarification.